# Mergecap not working

Tags: macos, merge, pcap, tshark

I have mergecap in `/usr/local/bin`, however I cannot see its manual (`man mergecap`). When I try to use mergecap, I get error 
`-bash: mergecap: command not found`

My path is 
`/Users/Umar/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS`

I am using OS X

Question: Can anyone guide me what can be the issue here ?

Comment: My guess is that the `mergecap` in `/usr/local/bin` is a symlink to something that doesn't exist. Try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mergecap` and see if the first letter is `l` and there is an arrow (`->`) to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You have misspelt it...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Yeah I noticed .. I have corrected it. I am trying to fix the path now to connect it to wireshark

Comment: @MarkSetchell, am I supposed to see **manual** of mergecap by `man mergecap` as now I have fixed the path and after `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mergecap`, I see `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    11B Dec 24 11:21 mergecap -> ./wireshark` but still when I enter `man mergecap`, I get `No manual entry for mergecap`